# How can I install the latest version (from the sources)

Tags: npm, npm-install, docsify

`npm install docsify -g` installs an old version ('4.3.0', while latest dev version is '4.9.4' (on git-hub)).

So I cloned [the git repo](https://github.com/docsifyjs/docsify), and from there ran `npm install`, but that seems not to do anything useful; at least there is no `docsify` executable in my *PATH* afterwards.

(on Debian testing)

Comment: mention your OS please in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install [git_url]
```

Just like this.